# Sending Actions variable to a method

Tags: java, appium

I would just like to know how to send an Actions variable to another method. Sample code is as follow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Actions a = new Actions(driver); \\.....line 1
    methodA();
}
static void methodA(){
    a.moveEelement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(" some path ").click().build().perform(); //error line
}
```

As noted above, the line with the comment `\\error line` is where the issue is, as the variable a is not part of the main method.

Keyword `static` when declaring variable `a` at line 1 is wrong. Selenium mentioned that only `Final` can be used, but not in my case.

I need advise on what way to allow me to utilise the variable `a` in the method `methodA`

Comment: instantiate the Action variable ```a``` outside of main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instantiate the Action variable `a` outside of main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Actions a = new Actions(driver); \\.....line 1
    methodA();
}
```

should be like below:

```
static Actions a = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    a = new Actions(driver);
    methodA();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pkm, but can can you advise me on the reason to have static Actions a = null instead of static Actions a; ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Variable "a" is not accessible inside "methodA". Please pass it as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Actions a = new Actions(driver); \\.....line 1
    methodA(a);
}
static void methodA(Actions a){
    a.moveEelement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(" some path ").click().build().perform(); //error line
}
```